# Type X cannot be used to index type error on type for object property 2 levels deep

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract the type of the property `prop` (in my code it could be anything) somewhere deep in my object `obj`, but TS gives a weird error about not being able to index the object in question.

This code

```
const obj = {
    prop1: {
        prop1_1: {
            prop: '123'
        }
    },
    prop2: {
        prop2_1: {
            prop: '123'
        }
    }
};

type Obj = typeof obj;
type Prop<
    Lvl1Key extends keyof Obj,
    Lvl2Key extends keyof Obj[Lvl1Key]
> = Obj[Lvl1Key][Lvl2Key]['prop'];
```

Gives this error:

```
Type '"prop"' cannot be used to index type '{ prop1: { prop1_1: { prop: string; }; }; prop2: { prop2_1: { prop: string; }; }; }[Lvl1Key][Lvl2Key]
```

But if I remove `['prop']` from `Prop` type declaration and try to see the resolved type on a variable, it looks fine and allows me to index the `prop` property on a variable without error:

```
type Obj = typeof obj;
type Prop<
    Lvl1Key extends keyof Obj,
    Lvl2Key extends keyof Obj[Lvl1Key]
> = Obj[Lvl1Key][Lvl2Key];

// this has 'string' type, no errors
let abc: Prop<'prop1', 'prop1_1'>['prop'];
```

---

**Edit 1**:
No errors in simpler config:

```
const obj = {
    prop1: {
        prop: '123'
    },
    prop2: {
        prop: '123'
    }
};

type Obj = typeof obj;
type Prop<
    Lvl1Key extends keyof Obj,
> = Obj[Lvl1Key]['prop'];

// this has 'string' type, no errors
let abc: Prop<'prop1'>;
```

Comment: Are you primarily asking why your current version isn't working or how to do it properly?  They are two different questions with two different possible approaches to answer.  One involves finding GitHub issues or other documentation, the other involves writing a functioning implementation.  If it's the former then it's [ms/TS#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760). If it's the latter then [here are two possible implementations](https://tsplay.dev/WyzAAw)... if that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Within your generic, when you access `Obj[Lvl1Key]`, it's possible for `Lvl1Key` to be the full union `keyof Obj`. This upper bound of `Obj[Lvl1Key]` looks like this:

```js
prop1_1: {
        prop: string;
    };
} | {
    prop2_1: {
        prop: string;
    };
}
```

The members of this union share no overlapping property names, so in this case `Lvl2Key extends keyof Obj[Lvl1Key]`, which is effectively `keyof Obj[keyof Obj]`, is going to be `never`.

So, within your generic, TypeScript has to consider that you may be trying to access `Obj[keyof Obj][never]['prop']`, but obviously that's not allowed. Hence the error.

However, once you are using your generic without the `['prop']` part, TypeScript is able to collapse things down to the single literal types you have specified, and so it then knows that the resulting type has a property called `prop` that you can index into.

With the example you've given, I'm not sure what's stopping you from simply accessing the properties directly without needing a generic type in the middle, e.g. `typeof obj['prop1']['prop1_1']['prop']`, so I'm not sure if there's a better solution I could suggest.